# Is it true that any matrix can be decomposed into product of rotation, reflection, shear, scaling and projection matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

It seems to me that any linear transformation in ${\Bbb R}^{n \times m}$ is just a series of applications of rotation — actually i think any rotation can be achieved by applying two reflections, but not sure — reflection, shear, scaling and projection transformations. One or more of each kind in some order. This is how I have been imagining it to myself, but I was unable to find proof of this on the internet. Is this true? And if this is true, is there a way to find such a decomposition?

EDIT: to make it clear, I am asking whether it is true that
$\forall A \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times m}  $,

$$ A = \prod_{i=1}^{k} P_i $$

where $P_i$ is rotation, reflection, shear, scaling, or projection matrix in ${\Bbb R}^{n_i\times m_i}$. Also, $n, m, k \in {\Bbb N}$, and $n_i, m_i \in {\Bbb N}$ for all $I$. And, if it is true, then how can we decompose it into that product?

Comment: The generality in which "linear transformation" makes sense is not the generality in which the other terms you're using make sense.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you elaborate?

Comment: "Linear transformation" makes sense for vector spaces over any field, as does "shear" and "scaling." However, to define a notion of "rotation" requires an inner product (so we should ideally be working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and depending on what you want out of "projection" or "reflection" those notions may also require an inner product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, I had in mind matrices of real numbers when I asked this question. I modified my question to reflect that.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/extracting-rotation-scale-values-from-2d-transformation-matrix ?

Comment: Similar  decomposition applies to [Mobius Transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_transformation#Decomposition_and_elementary_properties)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, what is shear and scaling in finite fields for example, or non-zero characteristic? My understanding is that most generally projections are idempotents, and reflections are involutions (but perhaps don't exist in certain classes of fields).

Comment: @alan: a shear in two dimensions is a Jordan block with eigenvalue $1$ and scaling is just multiplication by a scalar (multiple of the identity matrix).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The question is not posed completely clearly, but I think that something close to what the questioner wants should follow quickly from the [singular value decomposition](http://www.math.umn.edu/~lerman/math5467/svd.pdf), which states that any real matrix $A$ can be written in the form
$$
A=UDV,
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are square real orthogonal matrices and $D$ is a (possibly rectangular) diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries on the diagonal.  Since $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal they are products of rotations and reflections, while $D$ can be thought of as a product of projections and scalings.

For example, if
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&2x\\0&1\end{array}\right), 
$$
then
$$
A=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos \phi&-\sin\phi\\\sin\phi&\cos\phi\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}\sqrt{x^2+1}-x&0\\0&\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right),
$$
where
$$
\phi=-\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan x, \qquad
\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan x.
$$

In reply to the comments below: Interpreting a diagonal matrix with positive entries along the diagonal as a scaling relies on allowing the scaling to be non-uniform, i.e., allowing it to scale different axes by different amounts.  If the scaling matrices are restricted to be uniform, then, by using examples like the one above, you can write a square diagonal matrix with positive entries as a product of orthogonal matrices, shears, and a uniform scaling.

Comment: So it means that shear is also a product of reflections, projections and scaling? Can that be true?

Comment: I added an example of the SVD of a shear above.

Comment: How can a diagonal matrix be thought of as a product of projections and scalings? [Also, the middle matrix in your decomposition of the shear isn't diagonal.]

Comment: I made a typographical error; thank you for spotting that.  A diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries projects onto the set of axes given by its non-zero entries, and then scales these axes.  The scaling may be non-uniform as the diagonal matrix may use a different scale factor for each axis.

Comment: So are you saying that every positive semidefinite diagonalizable matrix is a scaling? I had assumed that "scaling" means a scalar multiple of the identity, and certainly no invertible diagonal matrix is a product of (orthogonal) projections and scalar multiples of $I$.

Comment: In some lines of work, it's common to call a diagonal matrix with positive entries a "scaling matrix", although, as you point out, it's not a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: This interpretation makes me wonder -- why do we need two rotations (since both $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal)? Why not just one? Isn't one enough to express any rotation in the final composite transformation?

Comment: "square real orthogonal matrices": if it's an orthogonal matrix, it's a square and real matrix, so it's redundant to write "square real orthogonal matrices", isn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Answer (score 8):

There are several things that are true and known for a long time, related to the question. First, we can consider non-singular matrices without much loss of generality, since any singular matrix can be written (in many ways) as non-singular composed with (orthogonal) projection.

As in another answer, the "singular value decomposition" (an example of a Cartan decomposition, valid in many other scenarios) expresses an arbitrary non-singular (real, for specificness) matrix as a product of rotation, diagonal matrix, and another rotation. Yes, this does express "shearing" as such a composition.

Another decomposition of non-singular real matrices is as a product of shear (upper triangular with 1's on the diagonal), diagonal, and then rotation. Among its other names, this is a special case of "Iwasawa decomposition".

Yet another is as product of upper triangular, permutation matrix (=exactly one non-zero entry, a "1", in each row and column), then another shear. This is a special case of "Bruhat decomposition".

Yes, each of these applies to the components of the others.

Answer (score 4):

The claim "any linear transformation is a series of applications projection transformations" is not correct. J. A. Erdos showed that every noninvertible $n\times n$ matrix is a finite product of projection matrices. An elmentary proof can be found here [An Elementary Proof That Every Singular Matrix Is a Product of Idempotent Matrices by J. Araújo and J. D. Mitchell, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 112, No. 7 (Aug. - Sep., 2005), pp. 641-645]
And it is not the case for invertible matrices generally.

Comment: If "any linear transformation is a series of applications projection transformations" is not true, I don't see how it says anything about "any linear transformation is a series of applications of projection, shear,reflection,rotation and scaling transformations". Now if it was true, then that is different matter :)

Answer (score 0):

For every real $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, we have singular value decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\Sigma\mathbf{V}$, where both $\mathbf{U},\mathbf{V}$ are orthogonal matrix, and $\Sigma$ is diagonal matrix. Note that this decomposition is not unique, and we can choose $\mathbf{V}, \mathbf{U}$ with determinant $+1$.

Consider the following facts:

- Every orthogonal matrix with determinant $+1$ could be decomposed to products of Givens rotation. [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017481/can-every-orthogonal-matrix-be-written-as-a-product-of-givens-rotations)
- [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) correponds to rotation in a subplane spanned by 2 orthogonal basis with one-hot coordinate.
- Therefore, every orthogonal matrix corresponds to a series of rotation in 2-dimensional subspaces.
- Real diagonal matrix corresponds to scaling at all directions.
- Operations like reflection and shearing could be decomposed to rotation and scaling.

We can see that linear map represented real matrix could always be decomposed into a series of  rotations, one scaling at each direction, and another series of rotations.