# Decomposition of shear matrix into rotation & scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

How can I decompose the affine transformation:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&\text{shear}_x\\\text{shear}_y&1\end{bmatrix}$$

into rotation and scaling primitives?

$$ \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
\begin{bmatrix}\text{scale}_x&0\\0&\text{scale}_y\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Just spacing. Removed for clarity.

Comment: As a matter of terminology I would call a generic transformation of the second "primitive" type *diagonal with respect to the standard basis*, not a scaling, which I'd reserve for dilations, i.e. *scalar* multiples of the identity.

Comment: This solves a similar problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109108/is-it-true-that-any-matrix-can-be-decomposed-into-product-of-rotation-reflection

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if $\textrm{shear}_x = -\textrm{shear}_y$, in which case

$$
\begin{align}
\theta &= \textrm{atan}(\textrm{shear}_y)\\
\textrm{scale}_y&=\sqrt{\textrm{shear}_y^2 + 1}\\
\textrm{scale}_x&=-\sqrt{\textrm{shear}_y^2 + 1}\\
\end{align}
$$

---

To see this we can identify both matrices:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1& \text{shear}_x \\ \text{shear}_y&1\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\text{scale}_x&0\\0&\text{scale}_y\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1& \text{shear}_x \\ \text{shear}_y&1\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}\text{scale}_x~\cos\theta&-\text{scale}_y~\sin\theta\\ \text{scale}_x~\sin\theta&\text{scale}_y~\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which yields the following equation system:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
1 &= \text{scale}_x~\cos\theta\\
1 &= \text{scale}_y~\cos\theta\\
\text{shear}_x &= -\text{scale}_y~\sin\theta\\
\text{shear}_y &= \text{scale}_x~\sin\theta\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

. This can only work if neither $\text{scale}_x$, $\text{scale}_y$, or $\cos\theta$ are zero. If that is the case, then we can immediately see that the scaling is isotropic ($\text{scale}_x=\text{scale}_y=\textrm{scale}$) and that

$$\textrm{scale} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$

. We can use this to simplify the other two equations

$$
\begin{align}
\text{shear}_x &= - \frac{1}{\cos\theta}~\sin\theta = - \tan\theta\\
\text{shear}_y &=  \frac{1}{\cos\theta}~\sin\theta = \tan\theta\\
\end{align}
$$

. Both can only be true at the same time, if $\text{shear}_x = -\text{shear}_y$, yielding above constraint. From here, we can find values for both $\theta$ and $\textrm{scale}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\theta &= \textrm{atan}~\textrm{shear}_y\\
\textrm{scale} &= \frac{1}{\cos{\theta}} = \frac{1}{\cos(\textrm{atan}~\textrm{shear}_y)} = \sqrt{\textrm{shear}_y^2 + 1}
\end{align}
$$