# How to decompose negative scale from a transformation matrix?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

I have 4x4 transformation matrices that represents translation, scale and rotation of a given object in 3d space.

I found how to extract translation, scale and rotation assuming the scale is always positive, but in my case those matrices can contain negative values for the scale vector (the rotation/scale 3x3 matrix determinant can be negative).

Assuming those matrices with negative determinant, how can I decompose the correct values for scale and rotation?

Comment: Can you give a specific example? How can a rotation matrix have negative determinant?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer to a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3554913/711238