# "improper" rotation matrix resulted from decomposition of transformation matrix to Rotation and Scale

Tags: matrices, rotations, transformation

I'm working on a problem with building heterostructures with a atomic unit cell. The unit cell (A) can be repeated infinitely along the xy plane. The transformation matrices (a and b) transform the unit cell to a supercell (aA and bA) so now aA and bA are each made up of several pieces of unit cell A.

A, a and b are

```
         7   0   0         0    7    0         6    9    0
A  =   -3.5  6   0     a=  1    3    0     b=  3    3    0
         0   0   1         0    0    1         0    0    1
```

How can I find the difference in angle of rotation between A in aA and an A in bA?

We can see that there is no translation in the transformations. Also, as the supercells are made up of individual unit cells that do not change shape in the transformation process, there is no shear. Hence only scaling and rotation are present. Rotation will be about (0, 0, 0) on the xy plane.

I tried decomposing the transformation matrices like in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati/417813). This led to

```
     S_(xa) cos(t_a)   -S_(xa) sin(t_a)   0           S_(xb) cos(t_b)   -S_(xb) sin(t_b)   0
a=   S_(ya) sin(t_a)    S_(ya) cos(t_a)   0      b=   S_(yb) sin(t_b)    S_(yb) cos(t_b)   0
            0                 0           1                  0                  0          1
```

but the rotation matrices after peeling away the scaling matrix do not fit the rotation matrix form.

Can someone enlighten me on what is wrong/missing here?

Many thanks

Jacek

Comment: There are four variables in the original matrix $a$, while there are only three variables in the decomposition.  Therefore, the identification problem is overdetermined, and does not have a solution in general.

Comment: So physically, what is causing this over-determination? As in what extra transformation is matrices a and b performing that leads to the over-determination?