# extract rotation, scale values from 2d transformation matrix (more clarification)

Tags: matrices, transformation

I have read the questions related to my query [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13150/115956) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361242/713573). Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) I have calculated the scale, rotation and translation. Some mistake certainly I have done that's why I could not get the correct values.
Here are my detailed steps:

- **Step 1:** Initial div without tranformation
- **Step 2:** Next I apply different transformations:

  ```
  transform:translate(250px, 250px) rotate(45deg) translate(-250px, -250px) translate(38px, 250px) rotate(20deg) translate(-38px, -250px) scale(.5)
  ```
- **Step 3:** Now I calculate the transformation matrix for all above transformations and apply to the original div:

  ```
  transform: matrix(0.21130913087034978,0.45315389351832497,-0.45315389351832497,0.21130913087034978,310.61081520146786,-40.000898954115684)
  ```

and I get the same out put as in "step 2"

I am using [transformatrix](https://github.com/chrisaljoudi/transformatrix.js) module to calculate the transformation matrix.

- **step 4:** Finally I calculate the scale, rotation and translation based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) .

  ```
  transform: rotate(-25deg) scale(0.5) translate(310.611px,-40px)
  ```

And apply these transformations to the original div and it does not look alike the output of "step 2" or "step 3". I was expecting it would give me the combined transformations in scale, rotation and translation.

**My requirement:** Many transformations would be applied on the div by user and at the end I would allow to store the combined/final rotation, scale and translation to user.

Please let me know where am I doing wrong or is this not possible (to calculate the combined values).

Comment: Have you tried inverting the angle? I haven't looked into the details, but that seems like a natural candidate that might get messed up due to incompatible conventions.

Comment: @joriki inverting means `180 - finalRotation` i.e in may case `180 -(-25)=205` that is also not correct it should be 65deg. What does incompatible conversion mean? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31312907/713573) are visuals with code snippet for better understanding my problem.

Comment: Aha -- the $65^\circ$ is promising -- that's $-25^\circ+90^\circ$. So it's quite likely to be due to incompatible conventions -- perhaps one measuring angles with respect to the $x$ axis and one with respect to the $y$ axis?

Comment: Its matrix notation in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) that I was following, is different than standard [HTML convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function). @joriki Now its solved, still I would like to know what is incompatible conversion.

Comment: convention, not conversion

Comment: Oh yes! you pointed out correctly in your first comment itself, but I read it wrong in hurry. Thanks